# Conditional component declaration depending on time-dependent variable

Tags: modelica

Is it possible to declare (or re-declare) components depending on the value of a time-dependent **variable** (as opposed to a parameter)? Conditional declaration has been discussed here numerous times (e.g., [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835622/conditional-type-assignment-possible-for-a-parameter/), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668468/conditional-component-decleration-and-a-following-if-equation) and [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096859/using-units-components-in-modelica-based-on-a-boolean-condition)), however in those examples, the condition depends on a parameter.

My situation is this: I have two models, `NaturalConvectionHeatTransfer` and `ForcedConvectionHeatTransfer` that extend from the same interface `PartialHeatTransfer`. In a third model, I would like to do something like this:

```
model MyProblem
  // stripped other declarations
  input v "Velocity of fluid flow";
  replaceable PartialHeatTransfer heatTransfer;
equation 
  if v == 0 then
    // redeclare heatTransfer to be of type NaturalConvectionHeatTransfer
  else
    // redeclare heatTransfer to be of type ForcedConvectionHeatTransfer
  end if;
end MyProblem;
```

A conditional declaration like `Component blah if v==0;` certainly does not work if `v` is not a parameter. Is there any way to achieve my goal? My guess is "no", meaning I will have to re-think the whole concept. However, perhaps someone sees an obvious solution I am missing. Any suggestion how to work around this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. You can, however, model around it by adding both heatTransfer components and switch between them using some dummy components and equations.

http://dx.doi.org/10.3384/ecp14096183 has some implementation hints on how to do it in Modelica slightly inefficiently (and how tools could optimize some of those things away).

Comment: Thanks a lot once more! The paper gave some interesting insight. For now, I have done just what you suggested - declare both components and switch between them.